# Mongo query update: cant replace field with concatenated values

Tags: mongodb

I have a field in a collection that should have been made unique but isn't. I plan to do a onetime db update to make every record have a unique value for this field and then add an index to ensure duplicates don't occur again.

Since I know _id will always be unique, I planned to just concat the _id with the existing value for this field and use that as the new value for the field

E.g.

```
_id, uniqueField
1, a
2, b
3, b
4, c
5, d
```

Becomes:

```
_id, uniqueField
1, 1_a
2, 2_b
3, 3_b
4, 4_c
5, 5_d
```

Unique values continue to be unique, whereas the duplicates (that shouldn't have existed in the first place) can now become unique again

But my query below throws an error and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
db.collection.update(
{},
{'uniqueField':{'$concat':['$_id','_','$uniqueField']}},
{upsert:false,
multi:true
)
```

> multi update is not supported for replacement-style update

Answer (score 0):

Using a pipeline in the `update` makes this pretty easy.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "uniqueField": {
        "$concat": [
          {"$toString": "$_id"},
          "_",
          "$uniqueField"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true,
  "upsert": false
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vY-1Nkdx7LX).